# Using viewport rotate in R?

Tags: r, rotate

I am trying to rotate a viewport object in R. However, I end up getting boundaries for the rotated object.

Any idea as to how to rotate but not end up with these boxes?

Below is the code. m_cont, m_AK and m_HI are the maps.

```
library("grid")

vp_AK <- viewport(x = 0.15, y = 0.25, width = 0.3, height = 0.3)
vp_HI <- viewport(x = 0.36, y = 0.2, width = 0.2, height = 0.13)


tmap_mode("plot")
m_cont
print(m_AK, vp = vp_AK)
print(m_HI, vp = vp_HI)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please supply a reproducible example? Have you looked at these: https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-maps-of-the-usa-with-r-alternative-layout/ and https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/222799/8104

Comment: The box outline is turned off by adding `+ tm_layout(frame=FALSE)` to your `tmap` construction. But you also seem to have a big white background box that is clipping the underlying US map. This is probably fixable but if you can provide an example as requested it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `tm_layout(frame=FALSE, bg.color=NA)` to your maps.

The first option removes the frame, and the second stops the system painting a white rectangle over the viewport. It does create (for me) some warnings, which I am ignoring.