# Add raster inset to a raster map in R

Tags: raster, r

I need to plot an inset on my raster map showing a zoomed-in part of the map (according to specificed coordinates). Something like the image below (credit: David Wachsmuth, twitter).

[image]

I know there are a lot of resources on how to do it in ggplot2 and shapefiles, but I've found nothing about how to do it with a raster map. A reproducible example of my raster is shown below:

```
 kiwi <- raster(xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -56, ymx = 84, res = 1)
 kiwi[] <- sample(2:35, ncell(kiwi), replace = T)
```

And I would like to create an inset of the following coordinates:

```
clipExt <- extent(-120, 10, 70, 90)
f<-crop(df, clipExt)
```

Comment: Answers here might be of help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222799/create-an-inset-map-in-r